# Web - Menu is not responding the clicks just in the range 1024-1200

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Good Afternoon

For the range 1024-1200px, the menu isn't responding any click and not applying the effects of the menu.
It's weird because it's just for this viewport screen resolution.

If you access this website (https://www.webpulse.com.br/menuzord/icons.html) and use the device toolbar from Google Chrome and resize the window for the viewport (1024x1366px) you will see that the clicks are not responding.

When I set a viewport width to 800px and resize it to 1024px it works, but if I try to do this directly it doesn't.
I've tried on Chrome, chromium, and Opera on Linux Mint and the results were the same for this resolution.

```
(function($){

jQuery.fn.menuzord = function(options){
    var settings;
    $.extend( settings = {
        showSpeed: 300,
        hideSpeed: 300,
        trigger: "hover",
        showDelay: 0,
        hideDelay: 0,
        effect: "fade",
        align: "left",
        responsive: true,
        animation: "none",
        indentChildren: true,
        indicatorFirstLevel: "+",
        indicatorSecondLevel: "+",
        scrollable: true,
        scrollableMaxHeight: 400
    }, options);

    // variables
    var menu_container = $(this);
    var menu = $(menu_container).children(".menuzord-menu");
    var menu_li = $(menu).find("li");
    var showHideButton;
    var mobileWidthBase = 991;
    var bigScreenFlag = 2000; // a number greater than "mobileWidthBase"
    var smallScreenFlag = 200; // a number less than "mobileWidthBase"

    // dropdown/megamenu indicators
    $(menu).children("li").children("a").each(function(){
        if($(this).siblings(".dropdown, .megamenu").length > 0){
            $(this).append("<span class='indicator'>" + settings.indicatorFirstLevel + "</span>");
        }
    });
    $(menu).find(".dropdown").children("li").children("a").each(function(){
        if($(this).siblings(".dropdown").length > 0){
            $(this).append("<span class='indicator'>" + settings.indicatorSecondLevel + "</span>");
        }
    });

    // navigation alignment
    if(settings.align == "right"){ 
        $(menu).addClass("menuzord-right"); 
    }

    // dropdown indentation (mobile mode)
    if(settings.indentChildren){ 
        $(menu).addClass("menuzord-indented"); 
    }

    // responsive behavior
    if(settings.responsive){ 
        $(menu_container).addClass("menuzord-responsive").prepend("<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='showhide'><em></em><em></em><em></em></a>");
        showHideButton = $(menu_container).children(".showhide");
    }

    // scrollable menu
    if(settings.scrollable){
        if(settings.responsive){
            $(menu).css("max-height", settings.scrollableMaxHeight).addClass("scrollable").append("<li class='scrollable-fix'></li>");
        }
    }

    // shows a dropdown
    function showDropdown(item){
        if(settings.effect == "fade")
            $(item).children(".dropdown, .megamenu").stop(true, true).delay(settings.showDelay).fadeIn(settings.showSpeed).addClass(settings.animation);
        else
            $(item).children(".dropdown, .megamenu").stop(true, true).delay(settings.showDelay).slideDown(settings.showSpeed).addClass(settings.animation);
    }

    // hides a dropdown
    function hideDropdown(item){
        if(settings.effect == "fade")
            $(item).children(".dropdown, .megamenu").stop(true, true).delay(settings.hideDelay).fadeOut(settings.hideSpeed).removeClass(settings.animation);
        else
            $(item).children(".dropdown, .megamenu").stop(true, true).delay(settings.hideDelay).slideUp(settings.hideSpeed).removeClass(settings.animation);
        $(item).children(".dropdown, .megamenu").find(".dropdown, .megamenu").stop(true, true).delay(settings.hideDelay).fadeOut(settings.hideSpeed);
    }

    // landscape mode
    function landscapeMode(){
        $(menu).find(".dropdown, .megamenu").hide(0);
        if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Mobi/i) || window.navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0 || settings.trigger == "click"){
            $(".menuzord-menu > li > a, .menuzord-menu ul.dropdown li a").bind("click touchstart", function(e){
                e.stopPropagation(); 
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent("li").siblings("li").find(".dropdown, .megamenu").stop(true, true).fadeOut(300);
                if($(this).siblings(".dropdown, .megamenu").css("display") == "none"){
                    showDropdown($(this).parent("li"));
                    return false; 
                }
                else{
                    hideDropdown($(this).parent("li"));
                }
                window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
            });
            $(document).bind("click.menu touchstart.menu", function(ev){
                if($(ev.target).closest(".menuzord").length == 0){
                    $(".menuzord-menu").find(".dropdown, .megamenu").fadeOut(300);
                }
            });
        }
        else{
            $(menu_li).bind("mouseenter", function(){
                showDropdown(this);
            }).bind("mouseleave", function(){
                hideDropdown(this);
            });
        }
    }

    // portrait mode
    function portraitMode(){
        $(menu).find(".dropdown, .megamenu").hide(0);
        $(menu).find(".indicator").each(function(){
            if($(this).parent("a").siblings(".dropdown, .megamenu").length > 0){
                $(this).bind("click", function(e){
                    $(menu).scrollTo({top: 45, left: 0}, 600);
                    if($(this).parent().prop("tagName") == "A"){
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                    if($(this).parent("a").siblings(".dropdown, .megamenu").css("display") == "none"){
                        $(this).parent("a").siblings(".dropdown, .megamenu").delay(settings.showDelay).slideDown(settings.showSpeed);
                        $(this).parent("a").parent("li").siblings("li").find(".dropdown, .megamenu").slideUp(settings.hideSpeed);
                    }
                    else{
                        $(this).parent("a").siblings(".dropdown, .megamenu").slideUp(settings.hideSpeed);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    // Fix the submenu on the right side
    function fixSubmenuRight(){
        var submenus = $(menu).children("li").children(".dropdown, .megamenu");
        if($(window).innerWidth() > mobileWidthBase){
            var menu_width = $(menu_container).outerWidth(true);
            for(var i = 0; i < submenus.length; i++){
                if($(submenus[i]).parent("li").position().left + $(submenus[i]).outerWidth() > menu_width){
                    $(submenus[i]).css("right", 0);
                }
                else{
                    if(menu_width == $(submenus[i]).outerWidth() || (menu_width - $(submenus[i]).outerWidth()) < 20){
                        $(submenus[i]).css("left", 0);          
                    }
                    if($(submenus[i]).parent("li").position().left + $(submenus[i]).outerWidth() < menu_width){
                        $(submenus[i]).css("right", "auto");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // show the bar to show/hide menu items on mobile
    function showMobileBar(){
        $(menu).hide(0);
        $(showHideButton).show(0).click(function(){
            if($(menu).css("display") == "none")
                $(menu).slideDown(settings.showSpeed);
            else
                $(menu).slideUp(settings.hideSpeed).find(".dropdown, .megamenu").hide(settings.hideSpeed);
        });
    }

    // hide the bar to show/hide menu items on mobile
    function hideMobileBar(){
        $(menu).show(0);
        $(showHideButton).hide(0);
    }

    // unbind events
    function unbindEvents(){
        $(menu_container).find("li, a").unbind();
        $(document).unbind("click.menu touchstart.menu");
    }

    // Menuzord tabs
    function menuTabs(){
        function startTab(tab){
            var TabNavs = $(tab).find(".menuzord-tabs-nav > li");
            var TabContents = $(tab).find(".menuzord-tabs-content");
            $(TabNavs).bind("click touchstart", function(e){
                e.stopPropagation(); 
                e.preventDefault();
                $(TabNavs).removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass("active");
                $(TabContents).hide(0);
                $(TabContents[$(this).index()]).show(0);
            });
        }
        if($(menu).find(".menuzord-tabs").length > 0){
            var menuTabs = $(menu).find(".menuzord-tabs");
            for(var i = 0; i < menuTabs.length; i++){
                startTab(menuTabs[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    // return window's width
    function windowWidth(){
        return window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
    }

    // navigation start function
    function startMenu(){
        fixSubmenuRight();
        if(windowWidth() <= mobileWidthBase && bigScreenFlag > mobileWidthBase){
            unbindEvents();
            if(settings.responsive){
                showMobileBar();
                portraitMode();
            }
            else{
                landscapeMode();
            }
        }
        if(windowWidth() > mobileWidthBase && smallScreenFlag <= mobileWidthBase){
            unbindEvents();
            hideMobileBar();
            landscapeMode();
        }
        bigScreenFlag = windowWidth();
        smallScreenFlag = windowWidth();
        menuTabs();
        /* IE8 fix */
        if(/MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent) && windowWidth() < mobileWidthBase){
            var ieversion = new Number(RegExp.$1);
            if(ieversion == 8){
                $(showHideButton).hide(0);
                $(menu).show(0);
                unbindEvents();
                landscapeMode();
            }
        }
    }       

    startMenu();
    $(window).resize(function(){
        startMenu();
        fixSubmenuRight();
    });

}
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: what do you mean by "isn't responding any click and not applying the effects of the menu"?
------- 
for me , the desktop version(not mobile), has hover effect and nothing will happen when i click every item, not matter what resolution i use.

Comment: Yep, all the viewports that I've tested worked smoothly, but this case don't.
If you want to see just resize the browser for 1024x1366 to see that the effects won't be applied and the clicks as well

Comment: i asked : what do you mean by "isn't responding any click and not applying the effects of the menu"? i mean: what is behaviur when you click on item in menu? (in resulation above 1200)

Comment: Basically, the highlight bar doesn't appear and then click on the menu it's not registered.

Comment: so i'm unable to reproduce. in my pc, width >768 all works same. all resulotions (width=1300, width=2000, even 1024 x 1366 and every width between 1024-1200) have hover color, and has no bar and has no special click event (it acts as normal link).

Comment: yaya you`ve tried using this website (https://www.webpulse.com.br/menuzord/icons.html).

If yes, what was the version of the chrome that you've tested?

Second, try to do this test with the resolution 1024w x 1366h and see the results please, if you got the same probably it's a bug from the browser.

So i will try to decrease the version of the chrome for the version that you are using and see that this problem was fixed.

Comment: yes i used website. checked it one more time with 1024*1366, it has just hover color(no line or click). checked with above resolutions as well.

Comment: yaya wha'ts the version of your google chrome?

Comment: Version 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: This is pretty weird, I am using the same version if it's working for you, probably it's some bug with my browser.

Thanks for the help and tests yaya.

I really appreciate :)

Comment: you're welcome. actually i dont understand it. if i get it true, you can't see hover effect (color change) when you set your resolution to 1024*1366, right?

Comment: also try `new incognito window` , cuase it may be problem with one of your chrome extensions.

Comment: Yep, I  can't get the effects yaya.

Testing here, if I set 1280x900 and after this I go to the 1024 x 1366 works perfectly, but If I go to the screen resolution directly, the buttons doesn't work even the effects.

I've tried on the incognito mode and I've received the same error, I will try to uninstall the browser and reinstall again, probably it's some configuration idk

Comment: i think i get it. i reproduced a not working example, by setting resolution preset to `Responsive` (in chrome device toolbar). so perhaps you're setting resolution preset to `Responsive` and setting the size directly on the inputs. i think you shouldn't do this.try this instead: click on responsive(presets dropdown at top), and hit edit, and then add a device with "1024*900" and set device type to "Desktop".

Comment: yaya I've discovered the problem-based with your description.

Actually, the presets that Google provides to us are having problems related to the test of UI and functionalities, but setting new presets with browser agent fix the problem.
Thanks for the help and patience :).

I will include our tests and results below for further researches of people that might face this problem.

Comment: no problem, glad it helped :)

Comment: Actually i (and most of other developers) don't use "chrome device toolbar" for testing desktop (big resolutions), we use `cntrl -` and `cntrl +` and resizing the browser window, to set the big resolutions (changing zoom level changes resolution). "chrome device toolbar" is good for testing with mobile and tablet devices. you can also test desktop in it, but actually people use it rare.

Answer (score 1):

Good Morning

With the help of @yaya pro, we've found it the reason why in some browsers the menu isn't responding, related to effects and clicks.

It's just because some presets provided by the browsers can't work properly, so to fix this you just need to create a new preset and fill the information's correctly, putting the drp(device pixel ratio) and the browser agent.
For fill these informations, this website can help you to gather them.
[enter link description here](https://www.mydevice.io/)

Once more, thanks for yaya for help and support.

I hope this answer can help other developers to solve further problems.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use z-index and @media screen

Comment: The problem's not related to responsiveness.